# Put elements by class name in an array and alert it with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get all of the elements on a web page that have a certain class name and put them into an array? Then I want to be able to put the contents of that array in an alert box?

How can I put those elements id's into the array?

Answer (score 7):

If your browser supports [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), use that otherwise use one of the many cross-browser [implementations](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=getElementsByClassName) available on the web.

Natively, you would get them as:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nameOfClassHere');
```

This returns an *array-like* object, and you can traverse the elements like you would do in an array, but cannot use methods of an array on it.

If you're using a library like jQuery or MooTools, this task is made simpler for you. In jQuery to get all elements having the class name "myClass", and get their text content into a single string use,

```
var combinedText = $('.myClass').text();
```

Get id's of each matching element into an array using jQuery:

```
var arrayOfIDs = $('.myClass').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

If using MooTools, you can get an array of the text content for each element that has the required class using:

```
var texts = $$('.myClass').get('text');
```

Get id's of each matching element into an array as:

```
var arrayOfIDs = $$('.myClass').get('id');
```

Comment: To convert it to an array, you can do: `elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements, 0);`

Comment: +1 for thoroughness and examples in two libs, and noting `getElementsByClassName` does not work in every browser.

Comment: converting a `NodeList` will not work on IE <= 8, in this case doesn't matters because `getElementsByClassName` also isn't supported on those versions of IE hehe, but in the case of other methods e.g. `getElementsByTagName`, will not work, and the spec mentions: *Whether the `slice` function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.*

Comment: @CMS I had a hunch that IE was going to be problematic here, so thanks for the full disclosure :). "Implementation-dependent" has a very specific meaning here and everywhere else this phrase is used - IE will not support it :D